# In image classification, why do we usually minimize a cost function rather than maximizing it?

Tags: deep-learning, terminology, image-recognition, objective-functions, policy-gradients

I was watching a video about policy gradients by Andrej Karpathy. At [10:00](https://youtu.be/tqrcjHuNdmQ?t=604), it shows an equation for supervised learning for image classification.

$$\max\sum _{i} \log p(y_i \mid x_i)$$

I have worked with image classification models before, but I always minimized a cost function (aka loss function). I have also never seen someone maximizing a cost function for image classification in the wild.

- So, what are the advantages of a minimizing loss function over a maximizing loss function in image classification?
- Other than RL, which problems do we solve by maximizing a cost function?

Comment: The video [Why maximise 'log' likelihood?](https://youtu.be/ddqny3aZNPY) might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no difference between minimizing a cost function and maximizing a value function.  One can be the reciprocal of the other, or the negative of the other, for example.

Comment: It is worth noting that the function that the OP gives is in fact the negative of the usual multi-class loss function. I would hazard a guess that Andrej used it to make a more direct comparison with RL.